# Create ID column based and grouped on time frequency

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': [22/07/2022 7:37:59, 22/07/2022 7:40:51, 23/07/2022 8:37:59, 23/07/2022 12:22:00, 24/07/2022 7:15:59, 24/07/2022 9:16:59, 24/07/2022 15:00:02, 24/07/2022 15:24:10],
    'Name': [Josh, Hayden, George, Josh, Peter, Josh, Hayden, Peter]})

df

      Date                    Name
0     22/07/2022 7:37:59      Josh     
1     22/07/2022 7:40:51      Hayden
2     23/07/2022 8:37:59      George
3     23/07/2022 12:22:00     Josh
4     24/07/2022 7:15:59      Peter
5     24/07/2022 9:16:59      Josh
6     24/07/2022 15:00:02     Hayden
7     24/07/2022 15:24:10     Peter
```

I need to create a new serial ID column grouping by days but if there are dates on the same day where the difference is greater than 5 hours, I would need 2 different IDs. In the example I put, you can see how there are 4 dates from 24-7. In the new column, 2 IDs would be created, one grouping the first 2 and the other the next 2 because more than 5 hours have passed between the 2nd and the 3rd. The expected result would be:

```
      Date                    Name     ID
0     22/07/2022 7:37:59      Josh     1    
1     22/07/2022 7:40:51      Hayden   1
2     23/07/2022 8:37:59      George   2
3     23/07/2022 5:22:00      Josh     2
4     24/07/2022 7:15:59      Peter    3
5     24/07/2022 9:16:59      Josh     3
6     24/07/2022 15:00:02     Hayden   4
7     24/07/2022 15:24:10     Peter    4
```

Any suggestion about how to do it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest shifting the original date column then comparing it to a timedelta of 5Hours and using `cumsum()` to count whether there difference is of 5 hours or not.
With the following line I get the expected output:

```
df['ID'] = pd.Series(np.where(df['Date'] - df['Date'].shift(1) < pd.Timedelta(5,'H'),1,0).cumsum()).shift(-1).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Output:

```
                 Date    Name    ID
0 2022-07-22 07:37:59    Josh   1.0
1 2022-07-22 07:40:51  Hayden   1.0
2 2022-07-23 08:37:59  George   2.0
3 2022-07-23 12:22:00    Josh   2.0
4 2022-07-24 07:15:59   Peter   3.0
5 2022-07-24 09:16:59    Josh   3.0
6 2022-07-24 15:00:02  Hayden   4.0
7 2022-07-24 15:24:10   Peter   4.0
```

Comment: At the moment it doesn't work because first I get an error because the column is str format. Then I convert the column to datetime64[ns] but when I apply your code it doesn't group the ID, I get in the new column 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, etc in each row...

Comment: If I introduce one row for example '2022-07-22 05:37:59' that should be ID 1.0 with your code it's being 1.0 but then the other 2 rows of 2022-07-22 are 2.0 and all of them should be 1.0